# Syntax for setting default value to related records data

Tags: formula, lookup, default-value

Can I set a default value for a text field (name=Sales Manager Number) on the Account that is equal to a field of the same name (Sales Manager Number) on the user record that is related to the Account via a lookup field on the Account named Sales Manager?

- I have created a formula in the past to set a default value on other fields from the user record of the running user but not sure how/if I can accomplish this specific need.
- Basically, when a user creates a new Account record the need to select a "Sales Manager" which is a lookup to the User record.

  - They also need to populate the Sales Manager Number field on the Account but would like to have it prepopulated since it already exists on the User record they have selected.

Comment: So, why would Account.Sales_Manager_Number__c be a text field when you could use a formula field `Sales_Manager__r.Sales_Manager_Number__c` to always have the correct value whenever the account is inspected. You've introduced a data sync issue

Comment: @cropredy They already have the the Sales Manager Number field on the Account created as a text field and have been using it for quite some time now.

Comment: You could use a before save Flow to default the value if the lookup field is present. Since it is on Account, you can make the read read only using dynamic forms